# Waiting loop for http protocol cause 404

Tags: java, http, httpserver

I'm trying to build simple java web server. Every request from a client must be supported by a separate thread. I wrote something like this:

```
this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);

while (!this.isStopped) {
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientSocket);
    new Thread(client).start();
}
```

The run() function of HttpClient class:

```
public void run()
{
    try {
        InputStream input  = client.getInputStream();
        OutputStream output = client.getOutputStream();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        output.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK".getBytes());
        output.write(("\n\nWorkerRunnable: dd").getBytes());

        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HttpClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HttpClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

When I throw away

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

everything works good, but with this a browser can not connect with the server.

What is the problem?

Comment: a one second delay is a lot of time to wait for the initial acknowledgement.  does it work if, for example, you used 20ms rather than 1000?  Why put in the sleep at all?

Comment: I tried build a simple chat - this is the reason for so long sleep thread.
Of course when a browser want to connect with my server as the first request, the browser will reject request because it is too long. But when I send request in via Ajax request, then everything is ok.

Thanks for your help Russell!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `Thread.sleep(1000);` after the `output.write(...)` statements. You should acknowledge the client ASAP, then wait.